# Jwplayer 5 config settings? example player.swf?id=12

Tags: jwplayer, swfobject

Have a nice forum, what i wanna do is, to make code seen `player.swf=id` in source code and wanna be read the player in jwplayer5.i dont wanna show subtitle and url.The embed i use now is sending id to `config.php`  and to be read from there by player yet it shows source codes.My codes

```
<object classid='clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000' width='940' height='460' id='single1' name='single1' type='application/x-shockwave-flash'>
            <param name='movie' value='_jwplayer/player.swf'>
            <param name='allowfullscreen' value='true'>
            <param name='allowscriptaccess' value='always'>
            <param name='wmode' value='opaque'>
            <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />
            <param name='flashvars' value='config=_jwplayer/config.php?id=<?php echo $row['s_id']; ?>'>
            <embed id='single2' name='single2' src='_jwplayer/player.swf' width='940' height='460' bgcolor='#000000' allowscriptaccess='always' allowfullscreen='true' flashvars='config=_jwplayer/config.php?id=<?php echo $row['s_id']; ?>'/>
        </object>
```

**MY CONFIG.PHP ;**

```
<config>
        <provider>youtube</provider>
        <file><?php echo $row['s_video']; ?></file>
        <plugins>hd-2,captions-2</plugins>  
        <plugin>captions-2</plugin>
        <hd.file><?php echo $row['s_video']; ?></hd.file>
        <captions.fontSize>21</captions.fontSize>   
        <bufferlength>1</bufferlength>
        <image>http://jnlyrics.com/_upload/images/large/define.jpg</image>
        <captions.file><?php echo $srt[0]; ?></captions.file>
        <smoothing>true</smoothing>
        <backcolor>000000</backcolor>
        <allowfullscreen>true</allowfullscreen>
        <autostart>true</autostart>
        <http.startparam>ec_seek</http.startparam>
        <wmode>opaque</wmode>
        <abouttext>Jnlyrics</abouttext>
        <aboutlink>http://www.jnlyrics.com</aboutlink>
        <skin>_jwplayer/skins/NewTubeDark.zip</skin>
    </config>
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of your other question...